# Get visual graph of heap memory usage in Java over a span of time

Tags: java

I am currently using Visual VM to monitor the heap memory usage of my Java application. However I would like to somehow see the heap memory usage over a span of time and not just get a snapshot. Is there a way to do this using Visual VM? If yes, how? If not, what tool can I used to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux try http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php

if windows use RUN->perfmon

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried visualgc which comes with jvmstat?

http://java.sun.com/performance/jvmstat/

If you are willing to pay, YourKit (yourkit.com) has a pretty good java profiler.